# Increasing RAM of my VM instance deletes files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a VM instance on GCP and I wanted to increase the RAM.
I had a 10GB disk space and I had additional disk for 100 GB that I had mounted. I stopped my VM instance, increased my RAM, started the instance again and now I see that all the files in the 100GB disk are all gone. Is there a way to retrieve them?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just not mounted. I can't tell what OS you're using, but display what is mounted and compare that against what's available in the system. You may have to make a permanent entry in your mount table to get this to mount on the next reboot (like within `/etc/fstab` on GNU/Linux, for example).

Comment: I mounted it after I rebooted but I still cannot see my files.

Comment: Add all of your command output that's showing this to your question. The best I can do without data is guess.